# Set a Ember.CollectionView's selected item

Tags: ember.js

I have a collection view like this (CoffeeScript):

```
App.SearchSuggestionsList = Ember.CollectionView.extend
  tagName: 'ul'
  contentBinding: 'controller.controllers.searchSuggestionsController.content'
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.content.title}}')
    isSelected: (->
      /* This is where I don't know what to do */
      this.index == controller's selected index 
    ).property('controller.controllers.searchSuggestionsController.selectedIndex')
  emptyView: Ember.View.extend
    template: Ember.Handlerbars.compile('<em>No results</em>')
```

As you can see there's some pseudo-code inside the isSelected method. My goal is to define the concept of the currently selected item via this yet-to-be-implemented isSelected property. This will allow me to apply a conditional className to the item that is currently selected.

Is this the way to go? If it is, then how can this isSelected method be implemented? If not, what's another way around this to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I think it solves the case that you are looking for, with a changing list.

What we do is similar to the solution above, but the selected flag is based on the collection's controller, not the selected flag. That lets us change the "selected" piece via click, url, keypress etc as it only cares about what is in the itemController.

So the SearchListController references the items and item controllers (remember to call connectController in the router)

```
App.SearchListController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  itemsController: null
  itemController: null

App.SearchListView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: "templates/search_list"
```

The individual items need their own view. They get selected added as a class if their context (which is an item) matches the item in the itemController.

```
App.SearchListItemView = Em.View.extend
  classNameBindings: ['selected']
  tagName: 'li'
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<a {{action showItem this href="true" }}>{{name}}</a>')
  selected:(->
    true if @get('context.id') is @get('controller.itemController.id')
  ).property('controller.itemController.id')
```

the SearchList template then just loops through all the items in the itemsController and as them be the context for the single item view.

```
<ul>
  {{each itemsController itemViewClass="App.SearchListItemView"}}
</ul>
```

Is that close to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The trivial (or the most known) way to do this is to have your child view (navbar item) observe a "selected" property in the parent view (navbar) which is bound to a controller, so in your route you tell the controller which item is selected. Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/7Uk7J/) for the whole thing.

Example:

Handlebars template of the navbar

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="navbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">MENU</li>
        {{#each item in controller}}            
            {{#view view.NavItemView 
                    itemBinding="item"}}
                <a {{action goto item target="view"}}>
                    <i {{bindAttr class="item.className"}}></i>
                    {{item.displayText}}
                </a>
            {{/view}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>    
</script>
```

your navbar controller should have a "selected" property which you'll also bind in your view

```
App.NavbarController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [
        App.NavModel.create({
            displayText: 'Home',
            className: 'icon-home',
            routeName: 'home',
            routePath: 'root.index.index'
        }),
        App.NavModel.create({
            displayText: 'Tasks',
            className: 'icon-list',
            routeName: 'tasks',
            routePath: 'root.index.tasks'
        })
    ], 
    selected: 'home'
});
```

Then you have a view structure similar to this, where the child view checks if the parent view "selected" has the same name of the child

```
App.NavbarView = Em.View.extend({
    controllerBinding: 'controller.controllers.navbarController',
    selectedBinding: 'controller.selected',
    templateName: 'navbar',
    NavItemView: Em.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        // this will add the "active" css class to this particular child
        // view based on the result of "isActive"
        classNameBindings: 'isActive:active',
        isActive: function() {
            // the "routeName" comes from the nav item model, which I'm filling the 
            // controller's content with. The "item" is being bound through the
            // handlebars template above
            return this.get('item.routeName') === this.get('parentView.selected');
        }.property('item', 'parentView.selected'),
        goto: function(e) {
            App.router.transitionTo(this.get('item.routePath'), e.context.get('routeName'));
        }
    })
});
```

Then, you set it in your route like this:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'hash',
    root: Em.Route.extend({
        index: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(r, c) {
                r.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('navbar', 'navbar');
            },
            index: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                connectOutlets: function (r, c) {
                    // Here I tell my navigation controller which 
                    // item is selected
                    r.set('navbarController.selected', 'home');

                    r.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
                }
            }),
            // other routes....
        })
    })
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This solution works for a static list of items, like the different options in a app's navbar menu. You assign a tag or name to each one of them, then the selected property in the controller is given the value of the item you want to be selected.

But I'm intending to do it on a list of suggestions generated dynamically as the user types in a text field. This doesn't mean that your answer won't work, I just have to try it out and see what the differences are and how to cope with them. I'll come back here with my findings.

Comment: Also, the way the selected element changes is different. In a navbar, it's the click event what triggers the change, and in the suggestions list it's the user typing the up and down arrow keys in the keyboard what allows him to select the suggestion he wants. Again, not an insurmountable difference, only something to take into account when adapting your answer to my needs.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware this would be on user type or arrow keys. This might have a few more things to be implemented then, but the concept should be pretty similar if not the same.